# how do I get the html code for superscript MC

Tags: html-entities, superscript

I am coding HTML emails, and need the HTML numbers for superscript MC.

I found MD which is given below:

```
&#7481;&#7472;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: This site looks like a good resource, but I could only find `M` and `D`, not `C`: http://graphemica.com/%E1%B4%B9

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, but my browser isn't using a font that includes it.

**Raised MC**

```
&#127338;
```

Sample: 🅪

**Raised MD**

```
&#127339;
```

Sample: 🅫

**Alternative**

I tried looking up `M` and `C` separately.  While there is a stand alone `M` and `D`, it appears that there is not a "modifier letter capital c".

**Sources**

- [Graphemica: Raised MC](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%85%AA)
- [Graphemica: Raised MD](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%85%AB)
- [Graphemica: Modifier Letter Capital M](http://graphemica.com/%E1%B4%B9)
- [Graphemica: Modifier Letter Capital D](http://graphemica.com/%E1%B4%B0)

Answer (score 0):

use html "sup" tag

```
<sup>text here will show up as superscript, but without css will be same size as font before tags</sup>
```

put text that you want in superscript - between above tags

I want to make super<sup>script</sup>

if you want the superscript text smaller than font before tags, then try css....

css style (example below):

```
.example {
  font-family: serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: .5em;
  vertical-align: .7em
}
```